# How to style svg progress bar with gradients

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, progress-bar

I'm using `progressbar.js` plugin, which helps me to create nice progress bars using `svg`. Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/xqge4cew/1/

In `#container1` I'm using hex colors to style the svg, but in `#container` I need it to be styled with gradient. As you see, it does not work. Is there a way to style svg using gradients?

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#7db9e8 100%)',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

var bar1 = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container1, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#eee',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

bar1.animate(1.0);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container1 {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use gradient as a color as it will be later placed inside the stroke. To use gradient with SVG you need first to define it then apply it as color. So you can try something like this:

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var Gradient = '<defs><linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1e5799"/><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2989d8"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8"/></linearGradient></defs>';

var bar = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: 'url(#gradient)',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});
bar.svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', Gradient);

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

var bar1 = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container1, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#eee',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

bar1.animate(1.0);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container1 {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
```

Comment: Nice one. Thank you!

Comment: +1 ... So this gradient spans the semi circle... I'm just wondering, how would you configure the gradient to span a greater section of the circle so that it doesn't repeat. For example in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/bLWZYY) the gradient is repeated twice

Comment: @Danield you mean what it repaet ? :) it's not in your pen ... it's going from right to left on the whole circle

Comment: I want the gradient to go from solid pink at 0 deg to solid yellow at 360deg - is that possible?

Comment: @Danield ah ok, by the way it's not the case with the semi-circle to as the direction is right to left ... what you are looking for is a conical-gradient which is not yet supported everywhere also don't think there is a svg element for it ... but we can always try to simulate it by using two gradient like this; https://jsfiddle.net/rq2ve5sx/1/

Comment: @Danield and to make the whole thing better and more accurate, you can adjust the animation like this : https://jsfiddle.net/rq2ve5sx/3/ ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have to insert the gradient color and then append it to the svg like this

```js
// progressbar.js@1.0.0 version is used
// Docs: http://progressbarjs.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/

var bar = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: 'url(#gradient)',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});
bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0

let linearGradient = `
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="20%" stop-color="tomato"/>
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="purple"/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
`

bar.svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', linearGradient);

var bar1 = new ProgressBar.SemiCircle(container1, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: '#eee',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});

bar1.animate(1.0);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#container1 {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container1"></div>
```