# How to put a gradient on a specific path with progressBar.js?

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

I was looking at this topic to get some help, [How to style svg progress bar with gradients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741796/how-to-style-svg-progress-bar-with-gradients) .

The problem is when i want to use this method on a spécific path, it's not working at all. I surely made some mistake when i use the doc, any help is welcome

```
var Gradient = '<defs><linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1e5799"/><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2989d8"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8"/></linearGradient></defs>';

var bar = new ProgressBar.Path(heartpath, {
  strokeWidth: 6,
  easing: 'easeInOut',
  duration: 1400,
  color: 'url(#gradient)',
  trailColor: '#eee',
  trailWidth: 1,
  svgStyle: null
});
var parent = bar.parentNode;
parent.svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', Gradient);

bar.animate(1.0);  // Number from 0.0 to 1.0



<script src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Calque_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
                    viewBox="0 0 175.2 155.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 175.2 155.9; overflow: inherit !important" xml:space="preserve">

                    <path fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke="#bbb" d="M33.3,154.5C14.2,138.9,2,115.2,2,88.7c0-47,38.3-85.1,85.6-85.1s85.6,38.1,85.6,85.1c0,26.4-12.1,50-31.2,65.7" />
                    <path id="heartpath" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="20"  d="M33.3,154.5C14.2,138.9,2,115.2,2,88.7c0-47,38.3-85.1,85.6-85.1s85.6,38.1,85.6,85.1c0,26.4-12.1,50-31.2,65.7" />
                </svg>
</div>




#container {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/dnLLgm5o/6282/

Answer (score 1):

If doing it through JS is not mandatory you should just add the `<defs>` containing the gradient to your SVG.

To do so take the content of ...

```
var Gradient = '<defs><linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#1e5799"/><stop offset="50%" stop-color="#2989d8"/><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#7db9e8"/></linearGradient></defs>';
```

... and add it after the oppenning `<svg>` tag

Then just add the stroke attribute to your path like that

```
<path id="heart-path" ... stroke="url(#gradient)" ... />
```

remove the color attribute from new ProgressBar.Path() and remove your line about parent.svg.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', Gradient); which is not nescessary anymore.

Here is what you should have.
https://jsfiddle.net/dnLLgm5o/6313/
Hope that's what you were looking for.